# How do I solve a recurrence relation of the type $a_{n+1} = K(n)a_{n} + P(n)a_{n-1}$ where $K(n)$ and $P(n)$ are rational functions?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I've been stuck on a problem for days now and was able to boil it down to this recurrence relation. I researched a bit about ways to solve it -- generating functions, characteristic polynomials, homogenous and non-homogenous recurrence relations -- but couldn't find a method of tackling this specific one. Any tips, solutions, or suggestions would be welcomed. Thanks.

Edit: As made clear in the comments, treating the functions as any rational function is too general to solve. The specific problem I am solving requires $K(n) = (2n+5)/(n+2)$ and $P(n) = (n+1)(n+3)^2/(n+2)$

Edit #2: As requested, $a_1 = 5 ; a_2 = 33 ; a_3 = 168$

Comment: Do you want a solution for the general case or are the $K(n)$ and $P(n)$ specific rational functions?

Comment: You can have a search for "P-recursive equations" or "Linear recurrent equation with polynomial coeffcients" but as it is a difficult problem in the general case, you won't find a magical formula. Though in some case when the coefficients are simple, you can try to find an ODE for the generating series and solve it.

Comment: @Giorgos Giapitzakis If possible. If it isn't, in my specific problem gives that $K(n) = (2n+5)/(n+2)$ and $P(n) = ((n+1)(n+3)^2)/(x+2)$. I understand that it may be too general to treat them as rational functions.

Comment: To clear up any possible confusion, please supply the explicit values you have for at least $a_0,a_1,a_2$ in your question.

Comment: Does the application require you to solve the recurrence?  Can't you just use the initial conditions and generate $a(n)$ using aloop?

Comment: @Doug unfortunately, I would need a closed formula for the program to run in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: I have come to an answer. I plugged the relation into WolframAlpha and it spit out $f(x) = 1/4[2(-1)^x(x+1)!+(x+3)!]$. Pretty neat! Although I am still left with no insight as to how this was solved...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> $a_{n+1} = \dfrac{2n+5}{n+2} a_{n} + \dfrac{(n+1)(n+3)^2}{n+2} a_{n-1}$

Rewriting $\,2n+5 = (n+3)^2 - (n+2)^2\,$:

$$
\quad\quad a_{n+1} = \frac{(n+3)^2 - (n+2)^2}{n+2} a_{n} + \frac{(n+1)(n+3)^2}{n+2} a_{n-1}
\\ \iff\quad\quad a_{n+1} + (n+2) a_n = \frac{(n+3)^2}{n+2} \big(a_n + (n+1) a_{n-1}\big)
$$

With $\,b_n = a_{n} + (n+1) a_{n-1}\,$, this telescopes to:

$$
\require{cancel}
b_{n+1} = \frac{(n+3)^2}{n+2} \,b_n = \frac{(n+3)^2}{\bcancel{n+2}} \,\frac{(n+2)^{\bcancel{2}}}{n+1}  \, b_{n-1} = \dots = (n+3)\,\frac{(n+3)!}{2} \, b_0
$$

Once $\,b_n\,$ is determined, what's left to solve is the simpler recurrence:

$$
a_{n} + (n+1) a_{n-1} = b_n \quad\iff\quad \frac{a_n}{(n+1)!} = -\frac{a_{n-1}}{n!} + \frac{b_n}{(n+1)!}
$$

Answer (score 3):

Based on the result by 2 False I suppose we can set $a_n=(n+1)!\ b_n$

This results in $$(n+2)^2b_{n+1}=(2n+5)b_n+(n+3)^2b_{n-1}=0$$

Applying now the idea by dxiv leads to an easier relation

$$(n+2)^2(b_{n+1}+b_n)=(n+3)^2(b_n+b_{n-1})$$

So we can set $c_n=b_n+b_{n-1}$ and get

$$c_{n+1}=\frac{(n+3)^2}{(n+2)^2}c_n$$

This is telescopic as well and $c_n=(n+3)^2\,C$

The equation $b_{n+1}+b_n=0$ has root $-1$

- general solution of homegeneous equation is $\alpha(-1)^n$
- RHS is $(n+3)^2\,C\,(1)^n$ so a particular solution is of the same degree $2$ as RHS.

Conducting the calculation gives $\frac 12C(n+2)(n+3)$.

In the end $$a_n=(n+1)!\Big(\alpha(-1)^n+\beta(n+2)(n+3)\Big)$$

We now have to apply initial conditions $a_1=5$ and $a_2=33$ and we find

$\begin{cases}-2\alpha+24\beta=5\\6\alpha+120\beta=33\end{cases}\iff\begin{cases}\alpha=\frac 12\\\beta=\frac 14\end{cases}$

> $$a_n=(-1)^n\frac{(n+1)!}{2}+\frac{(n+3)!}{4}$$

Verification: $a_3=-\frac{4!}{2}+\frac{6!}{4}=-\frac{24}{2}+\frac{720}{4}=-12+180=168\ \checkmark$